# Count Duckula episode where he meets a girl, but ultimately loses her due to the castle teleporting

Tags: episode-identification, count-duckula

I watched *[Count Duckula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Duckula)* a number of times as a child. I recently wound up on the TV Tropes page while following a wiki-walk, and it made me remember the bare bones of one of the episodes. One of the conceits of the show is that Castle Duckula can teleport itself anywhere in the world, but always returns at dawn. In this episode, Duckula met a female (presumably a female duck, maybe even a vampire female duck) that he fell head-over-heels for. I remember he was trying to find something to give to her as a gift in the castle when it teleported back, and for some reason, he couldn't just go back, so she was lost forever, returning us to the status quo.

I'm certain someone more familiar with the series will know this one straight off, but I'm not having much luck looking through the episode summaries.

Comment: There are people familiar with this series?

Comment: @Radhil I remember watching it, and having some of the books as a kid, but I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: @user25730 - yeah, that's pretty much all I knew of it either.

Comment: @Radhil - had a quick look through Wikipedia but can't find an episode which sounds like a definite match.

Comment: Count Ducula was awesome!!! I think I remember en episode about the castle teleporting, have a box set somewhere so will have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my memory:

I had this amongst other episodes on VHS video for my son back in the day so I ended up watching it many times!

The episode was 'Bombay Duck' and Duckula had dashed back to the castle for an "Ornamental Transylvanian Soup Strainer" to impress her.

The girl he had met owned a massive collection of Transylvanian Antiques but that was the one item she needed to complete her collection.

While he was rummaging his castle teleported back home.

Link to this episode on YouTube

Comment: That sounds right. Thanks